# how to add dropdown to navigation menu

Tags: html, css

I want to add sub menu in form of dropdown to my existing navigation menu. Below is my existing navigation menu code in html and css. I want it to dropdown when user hover over it. That is a dropdown menu that appears when user moves the mouse over the element. Please I do not want you to refer a link to me, I  only want you to modify my code. Obi

```css
.menu {
 border-bottom: 5px solid #00cc99;
}
.toggleMenu {
    display:  none;
    background: #666;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
}
.top-nav{
  background: #339933;
}
.nav {
    list-style: none;
     *zoom: 1;
    width:79%;
     float:left;
}
.nav:before,
.nav:after {
    content: " "; 
    display: table; 
}
.nav:after {
    clear: both;
}
.nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 9em;
}
.nav a {
    color: #FFF;
 font-size: 17px; 
}
.nav li.active> a, .nav li> a:hover {
 color:#FA6210; 
}
.nav li {
    position: relative;
   padding: 10px 70.5px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.nav > li {
    float: left;
}
.nav > li > a {
    display: block;
}
.nav li  ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
}
.nav > li.hover > ul {
    left: 0;
}
.nav li li.hover ul {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transition: background .2s linear;
 -moz-transition: background .2s linear;
 -ms-transition: background .2s linear;
 -o-transition:  background .2s linear;
 transition: background .2s linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="wrap">
   <div class="top-nav">
         <ul class="nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
     <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
     <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
     <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
     <div class="clear"></div>
     </ul>
      
   </div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Change `.nav > li.hover > ul` to `.nav > li:hover > ul`. Also add additional `<ul><li>..</li></ul>` inside your each parent <li> as your CSS already covered the code for child elements to be visible on hover.

Comment: Check this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/pz8oqeb5/

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. I noted that you were trying to show this by moving the menu back and forth.
You can use the "display: none;" to achieve what you are doing, and set it to "display: block;" when the parent li element is hovered.

Here's your code - I only commented out some things, and added some others.

```css
.menu {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #00cc99;
}

.toggleMenu {
  display: none;
  background: #666;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
}

.top-nav {
  background: #339933;
}

.nav {
  list-style: none;
  *zoom: 1;
  width: 79%;
  float: left;
}

.nav:before,
.nav:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.nav:after {
  clear: both;
}

.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 9em;
}

.nav a {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.nav li.active>a,
.nav li>a:hover {
  color: #FA6210;
}

.nav li {
  position: relative;
  /* padding: 10px 70.5px; */
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.nav>li {
  float: left;
}

.nav>li>a {
  display: block;
}

.nav li ul {
  position: absolute;
  /* left: -9999px; */
}

.nav>li.hover>ul {
  left: 0;
}

.nav li li.hover ul {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: background .2s linear;
  -moz-transition: background .2s linear;
  -ms-transition: background .2s linear;
  -o-transition: background .2s linear;
  transition: background .2s linear;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

ul.nav li:hover .hidden {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="top-nav">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a>
          <div class="hidden">
            <ul>
              <li>Sample item #1</li>
              <li>Sample item #2</li>
              <li>Sample item #3</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <div class="clear"></div>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Like this?

```css
.menu {
 border-bottom: 5px solid #00cc99;
}
.toggleMenu {
    display:  none;
    background: #666;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
}
.top-nav{
  background: #339933;
}
.nav {
    list-style: none;
     *zoom: 1;
    width:79%;
     float:left;
}
.nav:before,
.nav:after {
    content: " "; 
    display: table; 
}
.nav:after {
    clear: both;
}
.nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 9em;
}
.nav a {
    color: #FFF;
 font-size: 17px; 
}
.nav li.active> a, .nav li> a:hover {
 color:#FA6210; 
}
.nav li {
    position: relative;
   padding: 10px 70.5px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.nav > li {
    float: left;
}
.nav > li > a {
    display: block;
}
.nav li  ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
}
.nav > li.hover > ul {
    left: 0;
}
.nav li li.hover ul {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transition: background .2s linear;
 -moz-transition: background .2s linear;
 -ms-transition: background .2s linear;
 -o-transition:  background .2s linear;
 transition: background .2s linear;
}


.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.active:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="wrap">
   <div class="top-nav">
         <ul class="nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
            <p>Hello World!</p>
             </div>
          </li>
     <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
     <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
     <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
     <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
     <div class="clear"></div>
     </ul>
      
   </div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: The existing CSS from OP indicates, user will hover on the `<li>` element and the following `<ul>` will be appeared. `.nav > li.hover > ul`.

Answer (score -1):

As per your original CSS, you are trying to open dropdown on parent `li:hover`, however there is a typo(`li.hover`) which indicates the dropdown will open when the parent `<li>` has class `.hover`.

I modified the HTML to introduce sub menu and below is the navigation part of your HTML and CSS.

Note: The once the base HTML is setup for navigation, you can go ahead with any style and formatting for links.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2co53ts8/

```css
.nav {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
}

.submenu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}

.nav>li {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
}

.nav>li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  width: 300px;
  /*define dropdown width*/
}

.nav>li:hover ul li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```